# Index cannot be 3, only 0 or 1

Tags: c#

This error doesn't prevent the code from running but I would like to fix it. Here is the code,   error shows up under `HtmlElementCollection rows = Y[3].GetElementsByTagName ("tr");`
any idea will be appreciated.

```
doc.LoadHtml(content);
BindingSource datasource = new BindingSource();
BindingSource datasource2 = new BindingSource();
HtmlElementCollection Y = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table");

{
    HtmlElementCollection rows = Y[3].GetElementsByTagName ("tr");
```

Thank you

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: There are only 2 elements in `Y`, so you cannot access a 4th on index 3.

Comment: This code and any "bugs" will only be relevant if you supply the HTML associated with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
HtmlElementCollection Y = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table");
```

returns an array of tables. this array only has 2 items which is why your index can only be 0 or 1.
You cannot do y[3] because your array doesnt have a 4th element.

Comment: The reason I put Y[3] cause I want to access the third table in doc.

Comment: Y[3] is going to access the 4th table. arrays are 0 index based so 0 is the first instance. so y[0] = 1st, y[1] = 2nd, y[2] = 3rd.